# Singleton scope behaviour in a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to ask a question regarding Spring Beans.

Let us say we have a simple Spring Boot application and there we have a @RestController class. I want to know why is this previousFruitName not changing and keeping to null. Like if we have a singleton bean then it should remember the previousFruitName once /api1 ran for the first time. Its current behaviour is that it is keeping to null.

```
@RestController
public class Class1{
    private String previousFruitName = null;
    
    @GetMapping("/api1")
    public String method1(@RequestParam String newFruitName){
        
        System.out.println("previous fruit is "+previousFruitName + " and new fruit name is " + newFruitName);
        previousFruitName=newFruitName;
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: Runs here as expected. The code snippet won't compile (previousFruitName has no type), probably you are running old code.

Comment: sorry could you please elaborate what you expected. My expectation was that every time I hit /api1 previousFruitName should print the previous value. But it is giving null every time instead.

Comment: Correct, that is the expected and observed behavior to print the old  value before new assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works as you expected it to be. Only the private class field needs to be type defined as String.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private String previousFruitName = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api1")
    public String method1(@RequestParam String newFruitName){
        System.out.println("previous fruit is "+previousFruitName + " and new fruit name is " + newFruitName);
        previousFruitName=newFruitName;
        return "ok";
    }
}
```